# Delete mail from sent box automatically after sending it in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am using code from this [link](https://github.com/underbluewaters/secret-santa) to send details on email about their santee. I need to automatically delete all these emails from my sent box after sending the email. Can anyone help with it ?
I am using python 3.6

Comment: A *standard* SMTP server should not keep anything in *your* sent box. It should not even know about it. If you use POP to retreive your received mail, the `sent` folder is not known to the smtp server, because it is local and only managed by the mail user agent. Long story made short, do not use gmail and use your provider mail.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am not using Gmail. I am using my Company Email ID which we have configured using IMAP and not pop.

Comment: And have you really controlled that mails sent from Python did go in your sent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look into the API for your email client, and write a separate script that will comb through and delete the necessary emails.